# Injectivity of a map $\text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $f_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^i$ and $U_n=span_{\mathbb{R}}\{f_0,...,f_{n-1}\}$ for some integer $n>0$.

Why is the map $f:U_n\to\mathbb{R}^n, f\mapsto (f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$ for some distinct fixed $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ injective?

Comment: Hint: $U_n$ is degree $\leq n-1$ polynomials. $f$ is a linear map. What can you say about an element in its kernel?

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Elements of $U_n$ are exactly polynomials of degree at most $n-1$. So you're asking if for any fixed $\{a_i\}$, there are two different polynomials $g,h$ s.t. $g(a_i)=h(a_i)$ for each $a_i\in\{a_i\}$. (What we're really proving here is that polynomials of degree $n-1$ are determined by $n$ points.)

Let $g,h$ be polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ that agree on all $n$ points. Then $g-h$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ with $n$ distinct roots. But nonconstant polynomials of degree $n-1$ have at most $n-1$ roots, so $g-h$ is constant, and it has a root, so it is the $0$ polynomial. So $g=h$. This works as long as we have enough distinct points, which is why it sometimes fails in the finite field case.

Comment: n sufficiently "generic points," or in "general position"